# Couchbase query not returning not allowing parameter

Tags: python, couchbase

When I run the following Couchbase query from Python

```
mystring = 'XEXE%'

from couchbase.n1ql import N1QLQuery
row_iter = cb.n1ql_query(N1QLQuery('SELECT BoardAsString FROM boardwascreated WHERE BoardAsString LIKE $mystring', mystring))
```

I get the error

```
Error evaluating filter. - cause: No value for named parameter $mystring.
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Query variables need to be passed as named parameters in the python SDK.

For instance:

```
for row in c.n1ql_query(N1QLQuery("SELECT keyspace_id FROM system:indexes WHERE keyspace_id LIKE $test", test='test_val')):
    print row
```

In your particular case:

```
param = 'XEXE%'
row_iter = cb.n1ql_query(N1QLQuery('SELECT BoardAsString FROM boardwascreated WHERE BoardAsString LIKE $mystring', mystring=param))
```

The [official python SDK documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html) might be helpful.